# Pandas DataFrame: How to merge dataframe with multiple index and single index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I've a problem with merging 2 dataframe with multiple index in dataframe1 and single index in dataframe2. I have
dataframe1

```
ID    description
1          A
1          B
1          C
2          D
2          E
```

dataframe2

```
ID     price
1       100
2       50
```

expected output

```
ID    description    price
1         A           100
1         B           NaN
1         C           NaN
2         D           50
2         E           NaN
```

Thank you and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `.loc` with a boolean to drop duplicates and use `map` to find the values from `df2`

This approach assumes you only have one target column.

```
df1.loc[df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'],keep='first').index, 
                            'price'] =  df1['ID'].map(df2.set_index('ID')['price'])


   ID description  price
0   1           A  100.0
1   1           B    NaN
2   1           C    NaN
3   2           D   50.0
4   2           E    NaN
```

#### `.groupby('id').cumcount()` & `.merge`

Another, more dynamic method would be to create a sequence on your ID then join on both keys.

```
df1['sequence'] = df1.groupby('ID').cumcount()
df2['sequence'] = df2.groupby('ID').cumcount()

df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['ID','sequence'],how='left').drop('sequence',1)
```

---

```
   ID description  price
0   1           A  100.0
1   1           B    NaN
2   1           C    NaN
3   2           D   50.0
4   2           E    NaN
```

---

```
print(df1)

   ID description  sequence
0   1           A         0
1   1           B         1
2   1           C         2
3   2           D         0
4   2           E         1

print(df2)

   ID  price  sequence
0   1    100         0
1   2     50         0
```

Comment: Is there any way to hide 'sequence' using second approach?

Comment: @jong-hyeon-yeo yep, I've left it commented out, but you could `.drop` it on the merge I've left it in so OP understands logic of the merge